# What does the return keyword do in a void method in Java?

Tags: java, methods, return, void

I'm looking at [a path finding tutorial](http://www.cokeandcode.com/main/tutorials/path-finding/) and I noticed a `return` statement inside a `void` method (class `PathTest`, line 126):

```
if ((x < 0) || (y < 0) || (x >= map.getWidthInTiles()) || (y >= map.getHeightInTiles())) {
    return;
}
```

I'm a novice at Java. Can anyone tell me why it's there? As far as I knew, `return` inside a void method isn't allowed.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

It just exits the method at that point. Once `return` is executed, the rest of the code won't be executed.

eg.

```
public void test(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return; 
    }
    else if (n == 2) {
        doStuff();
        return;
    }
    doOtherStuff();
}
```

Note that the compiler is smart enough to tell you some code cannot be reached:

```
if (n == 3) {
    return;
    youWillGetAnError(); //compiler error here
}
```

Comment: I understand your code is illustrative, but for the parent's info; I've worked with people that believe each method should only have a single return statement.  I'm not one of them, but do believe in minimizing the number of returns as much as possible without making the code ugly in doing it.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not something to overuse, but sometimes it just makes it a lot easier and can still be very readable.

Comment: My favorite way of breaking from nested loops :)

Comment: Without a return value `return` works a lot like `break` in a loop and simply exits the code in question. There have been many flame wars about multiple exit points from functions and a few languages force you one way or the other. I don't take a position on multiple exit points, but I will point out that leaving a function cleans up the local stack.

Answer (score 32):

You can have `return` in a void method, you just can't *return any value* (as in `return 5;`), that's why they call it a *void* method. Some people always explicitly end void methods with a return statement, but it's not mandatory.  It *can* be used to leave a function early, though:

```
void someFunct(int arg)
{
    if (arg == 0)
    {
        //Leave because this is a bad value
        return;
    }
    //Otherwise, do something
}
```

Comment: Why can't we use `break` instead?

Comment: @fdama `break` only works inside a loop. There is no loop here.

Answer (score 29):

The keyword simply pops a frame from the call stack returning the control to the line following the function call.

Comment: Haha. This is great answer but I doubt beginners in java would really grasp what you're trying to say.

Comment: @ElliotMok Fair enough. We all start out as beginners!

Comment: Is this a good practice or doesn't matter whether we write `return;` or not?

Answer (score 15):

The Java language [specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.17) says you can have return with no expression if your method returns void.

Answer (score 5):

It exits the function and returns nothing.

Something like `return 1;` would be incorrect since it returns integer 1.

Answer (score 3):

It functions the same as a return for function with a specified parameter, except it returns nothing, as there is nothing to return and control is passed back to the calling method.

Answer (score 3):

See this example, you want to add to the list conditionally. Without the word "return", all ifs will be executed and add to the ArrayList!

```
    Arraylist<String> list =  new ArrayList<>();

    public void addingToTheList() {

    if(isSunday()) {
        list.add("Pray today")
        return;
    }

    if(isMonday()) {
        list.add("Work today"
        return;
    }

    if(isTuesday()) {
        list.add("Tr today")
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: The ArrayList should have been initialized as:  ArrayList<String> list =  new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 0):

void methodName() {

// body
}

}
``

}
The return statement should not be present within a void method, as a return value cannot be specified.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).