# What is the significance of the return statement inside a method whose return type is void

Tags: java

What is the significance of the return statement inside a method whose return type is void .
For example see this below program (I cant paste my companys code so i pasted some sample )

```
public class Pavan {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Pavan r = new Pavan ();

        r.kiran();
    }

    public void kiran() {
        int a = 10;

        if (a == 10) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Hi I am Kiran");
    }

}
```

Comment: it means the method stops at that point and return to the caller.

Comment: +1 I don't see what's wrong with this question that it deserves a -1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [return key word in a void method in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744676/return-key-word-in-a-void-method-in-java)

Comment: @ErickRobertson: actually what *is* wrong is that it's a duplicate (but that's not worth a -1). I shouldn't have answered ...

Comment: @ErickRobertson: I'll do that once this question got the close votes it needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It returns from the method invocation, i.e. it doesn't run any more statements after the return.

An alternative and equivalent way to write your method `kiran` would be this:

```
public void kiran() {
    int a = 10;

    if (a != 10) {
        System.out.println("Hi I am Kiran");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`return` in `void` method will just return from the execution of the function early.

It has such usage, but overusing it is not good. Use it if it makes the code clearer.

Answer (score 2):

return causes control to be returned to the caller, it doesn't necessarily mean a value should be returned to that caller. "return;" is effectively "return void"

Answer (score 0):

```
public void kiran() {
    int a = 10;

    if (a == 10) {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Hi I am Kiran");
}
```

It will stop  going ahead to that return statement mean `System.out.println("Hi I am Kiran");` will not be executed.