# What is the use of return statement in a void function

Tags: java, android, return

I m new to java, what does `return;` mean? is it like `break` ?

```
  public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
```

if the second `imageViewReused(photoToLoad)` returns true, `BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad)` won't be executed, right?

Comment: please go and read a basic (and freely available) java tutorial...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744676/what-does-a-return-key-word-do-in-a-void-method-in-java

Comment: Just my editorial comment but breaks and returns from a void method should be avoided : they are generally bad code design. Usually they can be avoided and in the example above you could do something like if(!imaveViewReused(photoToLoad)) { ... }.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Return statement skips the remaining execution of a function scope.

Worth reading:

1. `return` :
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html
2. `break` :
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: You could explain it... even in short!

Comment: void with return statement is special case just for terminating execution and return to caller ,better you imagine that he lefts basics maybe think it is just a special case

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a similarity but there is also difference

- `break` - will stop a loop and switch condition. Can be used only for switch, and loop statements
- `return` - will finish the function execution but the statements below of this keyword will not be executed. Can be used only for any functions.

**Usage of** `return` **keyword in void function**

If you use `return` in a void function like this

```
void trySomething()
{
  Log.i("Try", "something");

  return;
  Log.e("Try", "something"); 
}
```

the execution of this function is done but the statement(s) below will not be executed.

**Usage of** `break` **keyword**

for any loop statements

```
void tryLoop()
{
   while(true)
   {
      Log.d("Loop", "Spamming! Yeah!");
      break;
   }
}
```

the loop will be stopped and continue the remaining statements of this function

for switch condition

```
void trySwitch()
{ 
   int choice = 1;
   switch(choice)
   {
      case 0:
        Log.d("Choice", "is 0");
        break;
      case 1:
        Log.d("Choice", "is 1");
      case 2:
        Log.d("Choice", "is 2");
   }
}
```

using `break` in switch condition is also same as loop. Omitting the `break` will continue the switch condition.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can use it like a break.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `return` is break your next execuation of same block.

for more information about `return` [check this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Comment: *"Yes, `return` is same as `break` in java"* - this is simply not true. They're similar in a sense but they are definitely not the same.

Answer (score 1):

`return` ends the execution of the method in which it appears when it is called. For void methods, it simply exits the method body. For non-void methods, it actually *returns* a value (i.e. `return X`). Just be careful with `try-finally`: remember that the [`finally` block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) will be executed even if you `return` in the `try` block:

```
public static void foo() {
    try {
        return;
    } finally {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}

// run foo in main
```

```
foo
```

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) is a good reference for learning more about `return`.

---

> is it like `break`?

Well in the sense that both statements 'end' a running process; `return` ends a method and `break` ends a loop. Nevertheless, it is important to know the differences between the two and when each should be used.

> if the second `imageViewReused(photoToLoad)` returns `true`, `BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad)` won't be executed, right?

Correct - the method will "`return`" if the body of that `if`-statement is executed and no subsequent statements will be reached.

Answer (score 0):

A function's execution is finished, when it comes to the return statement and then it returns back to its invoking code. In your case,

if `imageViewReused(photoToLoad)` is true, then the code block after `return` will not get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here return act as end of function.
 You can avoid it by changing your code as,

```
 public void run() {
        if(!imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
        {
          Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
          memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
          if(!imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
          {
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
          }
    }
```