# What does return; (without value) mean?

Tags: java, return

I extracted someone's APK (Android app) to see the Java source code and saw a lot of `return;` code, even on `void` methods.

For example:

```
public void doSomething(){
do{
    return; //This line makes the code below unreachable and can't compile in Eclipse
    switch(num){
        ...
        default:
            return;
    }
}while(...)
...
}
```

How come the app seems to run well on my phone?

I guess `return;` is like a shortcut to break from the method. Is that right?

Comment: Decompilers aren't always perfect.

Comment: Every method eventually returns.  So a method with a `void` return type can either `return;` or leave it out.  It is not needed and is a matter of preference.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744676/what-does-a-return-key-word-do-in-a-void-method-in-java

Comment: @Vulcan so they are corrupted part of the code?

Comment: @squiguy it is more than a matter of preference. It serves a useful purpose that exceptions can't - it lets you end an execution path without breaking it. what I mean is that you can return and continue on the next line outside of that call versus throwing an exception and entering a completely different execution path in the first catch statement. so while its not needed in void methods all the time, it is still more than personal preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question: I assume this code is decompiled. Note that decompilers are not one to one converters of binary dex code to whatever Java code has been used to generate these binaries. They often have problems with parsing different control structures like loops and switches. Besides, the binary may be obfuscated, meaning that after compilation the binary is modified in a way to be fully operational, but harder to decompile and reverse engineer (basically to prevent what you're trying to do here :) ). They can add dead code, like return statement that shouldn't be there, mangle loops and if statements to confuse decompiled code, etc.

Comment: Thanks it does explains why all the `for` and `while` loops seem to have problem.

Answer (score 26):

If the method returns void then `return;` just exits out of the method at that statement, not running the following statements.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid yeah I think it returns nothing

Answer (score 11):

Yes, that is correct. Look at the bottom of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html:

> The return Statement
>
> The last of the branching statements is the return statement. The
>   return statement exits from the current method, and control flow
>   returns to where the method was invoked. The return statement has two
>   forms: one that returns a value, and one that doesn't. To return a
>   value, simply put the value (or an expression that calculates the
>   value) after the return keyword.
>
> return ++count; The data type of the returned value must match the
>   type of the method's declared return value. When a method is declared
>   void, use the form of return that doesn't return a value.
>
> return;

Comment: Thanks! I never knew that `void` method can use `return`.

Answer (score 1):

return keyword is used basically in a void method ,it helps to break the conditional statement to come out of method.