# How can I end a program during a try catch statement in Java?

Tags: java

I already asked a question about how to have a message pop up and say "please enter a number input" but it was supposed to end the program. Not crash it, but end the program then you would have to rerun it.

```
`    try 
 {
     number = in.nextInt();

       if(number >= 8) 
       { 
       number = 8; 
       }
       else if (number <= 0)
       {
       number = 0;
       }
   } 
   catch (InputMismatchException exc) 

   {
       System.out.println("Program requires NUMBER input");

   }
```

`

I tried doing a "break;" in the catch (experimented I guess) and it didn't work.

---

UPDATE: Thanks everyone, I tried return in a previous project and it didn't work. But it worked here so thank you again!!

Comment: System.exit()? Not terribly user-friendly, though.

Comment: Maybe try `return` :)

Comment: Post the code around the `try..catch` the whole `System.exit` idea is a terrible idea..

Comment: @LoicFaureLacroix It's only a "horrible idea" if it doesn't fulfill the requirements. There's absolutely nothing intrinsically wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `return` statement.  That should end the method.  `System.exit(0)` is an alternative option.  However, you must be cautious when using `System.exit(0)` because:

> The System.exit method forces termination of all threads in the Java
>   virtual machine. This is drastic....System.exit should be reserved for
>   a catastrophic error exit, or for cases when a program is intended for
>   use as a utility in a command script that may depend on the program's
>   exit code.

Source:  [Use System.exit with care](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=86)

Comment: Much better than `System.exit` because `System.exit` is like having every of your employee ending their work day by bombing themselves up.

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.exit();`

```
   try{
   ...
   } 
   catch (InputMismatchException exc) 

   {
       System.out.println("Program requires NUMBER input");
       System.exit(1);

   }
```

Or if your are in the `main` function, you can just `return;`

Answer (score 1):

Use `return;`, read also [What does the return keyword do in a void method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744676/what-does-a-return-key-word-do-in-a-void-method-in-java)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    return; // END OF PROGRAM :)
}
```

[Returning a Value from a Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

> `return` statement can be used to branch out of a control flow block and **exit the method**

Answer (score 1):

You can just make use simple return; at end of the catch block rather then System.exit(), it will kill the jvm.

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain you want the program to terminate you would just do

```
System.out.println("Program requires NUMBER input");
System.exit(1); // <-- non-zero to indicate an error.
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's in your `main` method, do `return;` otherwise you can do e.g. `System.exit(1);`