# For what aim used an empty return in this example?

Tags: java, return, try-catch

For what aim used an empty "return"(in the catch block) in this example?
(sorry for my english) 
Thank you in advance!

```
public class DeserializeDemo
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Employee employee;
        try
        {
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("E:\\serialization\\employee.ser"));
            employee = (Employee) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return; //this one
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
            System.out.println("Employee class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();
            return; //...and this one!
        }
        System.out.println("Deserialized Employee...");
        System.out.println("Name: " + employee.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the return keyword do in a void method in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744676/what-does-the-return-keyword-do-in-a-void-method-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

`return`, as the name says, exits the current method and returns to the caller. In your example, in case of errors, it returns without writing the final message, since it couldn't deserialize the employee.

Answer (score -1):

I've copied this from another thread

The Java language specification says you can have return with no expression if your method returns void. It functions the same as a return for function with a specified parameter, except it returns nothing, as there is nothing to return and control is passed back to the calling method.