# Is Java pass-by-value or pass-by-reference?

Tags: java

Why aren't variables I modify inside `myMethod` are not modified outside that scope?

```
public class TestLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myMethod(0, 3);

    }

    static void myMethod(int i, int j) {
        System.out.println("i for:" + i + " j:" + j);
        if (i == j)
            return;
        else {

            myMethod(i + 1, j);
            System.out.println("after myMethod Call for:  i:" + i + " j: " + j);
        }
        System.out.println("outside i for: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "rolled back"? The variables don't exist anywhere else than in the method, how can they be anything after return? If you mean that the call to the method doesn't change the variables outside the method then that's as it is. It has nothing to do with `return`, variables just don't change outside. How would `0` or `3` change?

Comment: just a recursive call and terminates when local variable satisfy condition `i==j` , read about local variables and return statement

Comment: you can `return;` in a void function, which kind of acts like a `break` inside of a loop

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744676/what-does-the-return-keyword-do-in-a-void-method-in-java

Comment: Your code seems to assume that calling `myMethod` can change the value of its variables. It can't. Java is strictly pass by value. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value If you want a value back from a method you call then you need to return that value.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/40523#40523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `myMethod(i + 1, j)`, new local variables `i` and `j` are created on the stack and initialized to the values passed to them by the caller.

When each execution of `myMethod()` returns, the local variables `i` and `j` get out of scope. You return to the previous `myMethod()` execution, which has its own local variables `i` and `j` having their own values.

Finally, when the call stack returns to the original `myMethod(0,3)` call, that execution has local variables `i` and `j` with values `0` and `3`.

The values of `i` and `j` never change. There are just multiple local variables named `i` and `j`, each one having a limited scope.

Comment: exactly same is happening as you mentioned but never stumble upon such thing. Would be great if refer somewhere more serious example. I saw this piece of code in a merge sort implementation.

Comment: @RoseK, you just didn't know the terminology for that, so you didn't have an easy way to search for it. This has been discussed on Stack Overflow and all over the Internet, so now you have a way to get more information, starting with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/40523#40523

Answer (score 0):

The [JLS - Chapter 14. Blocks and Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17) contains the answer for your question:

> The `break` (§14.15), `continue` (§14.16), and **`return`** (§14.17) statements cause a transfer of control that may prevent normal completion of statements that contain them.

The control is returned back to the statement where the method was called from.